# How can I position a pie chart within another plot according to x, y coordinates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

How would I go about positioning a pie chart to a specific location by x, y coordinates on a geopandas map plot using pandas and matplotlib?

I have tried first plotting individual points and then modifying the code but the same method does not appear to be transferable over.

-- Code for plotting points (`ax` is the axis of the subplot that the map plot is on) --

```py
ax.plot(x, y, color=color, markersize=size, marker="o")
```

The same method does not work for plotting pie charts and any other solutions I tried, such as creating sub-axes, seem to break the plot entirely.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `ax.pie(..., center=(x,y), radius=...)` [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Mind that you would have to determine the positions of your pie charts yourslef

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf = gdf[gdf.name == "United States of America"]


df_pie_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [-100, -90],
    'y': [40, 45],
    'category_a': [10, 20],
    'category_b': [30, 15]
})

def add_pie_chart(ax, data_row, sizes, coords):
    bbox = ax.get_position()  
    trans = ax.transData + fig.transFigure.inverted()  
    x_fig, y_fig = trans.transform(coords)  
    width, height = 0.1, 0.1  
    pie_ax = fig.add_axes([x_fig - 2*width , y_fig - 2*height, width, height], aspect='equal')
    pie_ax.pie(sizes, startangle=90) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 10))
gdf.plot(ax=ax)

for idx, row in df_pie_data.iterrows():
    x, y = row['x'], row['y']
    sizes = [row['category_a'], row['category_b']]  
    add_pie_chart(ax, row, sizes, (x, y))

plt.show()
```

Which gives something like this
[image]